# Get All Child SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table like:

```
oName     oPost    oPoint
A         1        NULL
B         2        1
C         3        1
D         4        1
E         5        2
F         6        2
G         7        3
```

So, If I select `oName = A` then the result should be:

```
oName
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

If I select `oName = B`, then the result should be:

```
oName
B
E
F
```

How can I do this on SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive `CTE` to traverse the hierarchy starting at your specified node:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(1);
SET @name = 'A';

WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT oName, oPost
  FROM data
  WHERE oName = @name
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.oName, d.oPost
  FROM data d
  JOIN CTE ON CTE.oPost = d.oPoint
)
SELECT oName
FROM CTE
ORDER BY oName
```

Output:

```
oName
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

Or, if you `SET @name='B'`, output is

```
oName
B
E
F
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=2a37cb2c67fb57669d4112b103abf1bd)